# If function not working when I add condition about cells with N/A

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get my if statement to give me a `Yes` or `No` depending on the value of the cell, which is working fine. The issue comes when a cell has `N/A` in it, it is giving me a `Yes`, and I need to give a `No`. But I can't seem to get the equation to work with that added condition. If either Cell is >59% I need it to say Yes, if a one cell is N/A and the other <59%, I need it to say No. If there is an N/A and a >59% it needs to say yes.

Here is my working `IF` statement:

```
=IF(OR(P11>59%, Q11>59%), "Yes", "No")
```

Here is my attempted `IF` statement with the added condition:

```
=IF(OR(P11=N/A, Q11=N/A),"No",IF(OR(P11>59%, Q11>59%),"Yes","No"))
```

Comment: The N/A is text written or is a result of a formula?

Comment: Does the cell say #N/A (the way #N/A means something specific in Excel) or simply N/A?

Comment: One more thing your can add in the question... If P11 is N/A but Q11>59%, would that need a Yes or a No?

Comment: IFERROR function?

Comment: Or ISNA function?

Comment: The N/A is the result of an equation that is supposed to pop out an N/A if hte equation sees a blank. I did try to change it so that is popped out an NA instead, but it still does not work with the if function. I need it to say Yes if either cell is >59%, but No if both cells are >59% or say N/A.

Comment: That doesn't answer is the N/A is a text written N/A or the system generated #N/A. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotation marks around `N/A`. Strings need to be enclosed in quotes `"N/A"`

```
=IF(OR(P11="N/A",Q11="N/A"),"No",  
    IF(OR(P11>59%,Q11>59%),"Yes","No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula `=IF(OR(P11=N/A, Q11=N/A),"No",IF(OR(P11>59%, Q11>59%),"Yes","No"))` is trying to divide N by A and returning a `#Name?` error as it's no idea what N or A is.

If your cell contains the text `N/A` rather than the error message `#N/A` then it needs to be treated as text:
`=IF(OR(P11="N/A", Q11="N/A"),"No",IF(OR(P11>59%, Q11>59%),"Yes","No"))`

If it contains the error #N/A then you can check for that:
`=IF(OR(ISNA(P11), ISNA(Q11)),"No",IF(OR(P11>59%, Q11>59%),"Yes","No"))`

Or you could check that the values are numeric:
`=IF(OR(NOT(ISNUMBER(P11)), NOT(ISNUMBER(Q11))),"No",IF(OR(P11>59%, Q11>59%),"Yes","No"))`.

You could also use `ISERROR` instead of `ISNA` to check for any type of error.

Comment: That worked!! thank you.

Comment: @Aubrey, note that this (the first one) will result in a No if there is one cell >59% and the 2nd one N/A, which doesn't seem what you want

Comment: Okay, so the equation is now at least functional, but it is giving a No for when there is an N/A in one column, but a >60% in the other. I need it to give a Yes in this case. Would changing the order fix this?

Comment: Changing the order will not fix it (because the test `P11>59%` returns a Yes for text.) See my answer for a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should give you the result you want, by testing each of the `OR` conditions also if it `ISNUMBER`:

```
=IF(OR(AND(ISNUMBER(P11),P11>59%),AND(ISNUMBER(Q11),Q11>59%)),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: When I used this equation, I get an Yes when one column is <59% and the other column is N/A, in this situation, I need it to say no. If there is one N/A and one value >59%, I need it to say Yes.

Comment: I had a typo there in the first `>59%` that it was also `Q11>59%` and not `P11>59%`. Check now the corrected one

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. If my Answer solved your question, please select it as the Accepted Answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.